# Java Displaying String on a JTextField after a JButton in a separate class is pressed

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jtextfield, arrays

Currently working on a school project in which I am making a wheel of fortune replica in Java. I have a panel of `JButton`s within a class called `buttonPanel`, and a separate class, `wheelGUI`, which acts as the class that the program runs through. What I want to happen is when the `JButton` `spin` is pressed on the GUI, it assigns a random value from `String[] wheelStuff` to a String, `spinValue`,using the method `spinWheel` which acts as the parameter for the `JTextField results`, and then displays that random value on the Cyan box in the GUI. In non-technical terms, when the button spin is pressed, display a random value in the Cyan box which acts as the current players' spin value. Here is the code for the class `buttonPanel`

```
    package wheelOfFortune;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class buttonPanels extends JPanel
                        implements ActionListener
{
private JButton spin, solve, buyVowel, guess, reset, end, cont;
Color yungMoney = new Color(0, 180, 100);
private static String[] wheelStuff = new String[]{"Bankrupt", "Lose a Turn", "$5000", "$600", "$500", "$300", "$800", "$550", "$400", "$900", "$350", "$450", "$700"};

public buttonPanels()
{
    setBackground(yungMoney);
    spin = new JButton("Spin!");
    spin.addActionListener(this);
    solve = new JButton("Solve the Puzzle");
    solve.addActionListener(this);
    buyVowel = new JButton("Buy a Vowel");
    buyVowel.addActionListener(this);
    guess = new JButton("Guess a Letter");
    guess.addActionListener(this);
    reset = new JButton("Reset");
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    cont = new JButton("Continue");
    cont.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,380));
    buttonPanel.setBackground(yungMoney);
    buttonPanel.add(spin);
    buttonPanel.add(guess);
    buttonPanel.add(buyVowel);
    buttonPanel.add(solve);
    buttonPanel.add(cont);
    buttonPanel.add(reset);

    add(buttonPanel);
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {
     JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
     b.addActionListener(this);
     if(b==spin)
     {
         wheelGUI.spinWheel(wheelStuff);
     }
     repaint();
 }

}
```

And here is the code for the main class, `wheelGUI`

```
package wheelOfFortune;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class wheelGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private playerPlate player1, player2, player3;
Color yungMoney = new Color(0, 180, 100);
private String fileName = "M:/wheelOfFortune/src/wheelOfFortune/img/wheel1.png";
private String cat;
private static String spinValue = "";
private static String[] wheelStuff = new String[]{"Bankrupt", "Lose a Turn", "$5000", "$600", "$500", "$300", "$800", "$550", "$400", "$900", "$350", "$450", "$700"};
private static JTextField results;

public wheelGUI() {
    super("Butt Stuff!");

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(fileName);
    JLabel picture = new JLabel(i);

    player1 = new playerPlate("Garrett", Color.RED);
    player2 = new playerPlate("Jonny", Color.YELLOW);
    player3 = new playerPlate("Robert", Color.BLUE);

    buttonPanels buttons = new buttonPanels();
    letterBoard letters = new letterBoard();
    catBox category = new catBox(cat);
    inputField input = new inputField();

    Box wall = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    wall.add(player1);
    wall.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    wall.add(player2);
    wall.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    wall.add(player3);

    JPanel result = new JPanel();
    result.setBackground(yungMoney);
    JTextField results = new JTextField(spinValue);
    results.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    results.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    results.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2));
    results.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
    results.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 28));
    results.setEditable(false);
    result.add(results);


    Box catInput = Box.createVerticalBox();
    catInput.add(category);
    catInput.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));
    catInput.add(result);
    catInput.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
    catInput.add(input);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(yungMoney);
    c.add(buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);
    c.add(wall, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    c.add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(picture, BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(catInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public static String spinWheel(String[] wheelStuff)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    wheelStuff[rnd.nextInt(wheelStuff.length)] = spinValue;
    return spinValue;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    wheelGUI window = new wheelGUI();
    window.setBounds(50, 50, 1024, 768);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    // logic for any additional panels. other logics should be in individual
    // classes.
}

}
```

Thanks for your help! Note: all of the code in `wheelGUI` that isn't related to something previously stated can be ignored, it's from various other classes.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `static` fields in this manner is not recommended.

Instead, the `buttonsPanel` should be taking a reference of the `wheelGUI`. This will allow the `buttonsPanel` to call the required methods on the `wheelGUI` when it needs to.

A better solution would be to use a model which can sit between the two UIs and model the logic, firing events as parts of the model change

Your primary problem is your shadowing the `results` textfield. That is, you've declared and class level, static field and then redeclared it within your constructor

Change the following line in your `wheelGUI` constructor

```
 JTextField results = new JTextField(spinValue);
```

To

```
results = new JTextField(spinValue);
```

This will mean when you set the text on the results field, you will be setting the value of the correct instance of the field.